# Does $ \mathfrak{A} \models (\exists x) \phi $ imply that $ \phi[x / t] $ for some term $ t $. Second approach?

Tags: first-order-logic

If $ \mathfrak{A} \models (\exists x) \phi $, does it mean that $ \mathfrak{A} \models \phi[x / t] $ for some term $ t $?

$ \mathfrak{A} \models (\exists x) \phi $. It means that there exists $a \in A$ that $(\mathfrak{A}, s[x|a]) \models \phi$ 
So, the answer for problem is: Generally not, it depends.
If the term $t$ is such closed formula that $[t]_{\mathfrak{A}} = a$ the $\mathfrak{A} \models \phi[x/t] $ is satisfied. Otherwise, not.

Comment: Basically : YES. We can always "enlarge" the language adding a *constant* $\overline a$ denoting the objcet $a \in |\mathfrak A|$, i.e. such that $[\overline a] ^ {\mathfrak A} = a$. See : Dirk van Dalen, [Logic and Structure](https://books.google.it/books?id=u0wlXPHATDcC&pg=PA63) (5th ed - 2013) : **Definition 3.3.16**, page 63.

Comment: Yes, we can add a constant, but, we have to add that constant to the signature of our strucutre. So, we modified a structure. Now, it is not the same structure $\mathfrak{A}$ still. So we cannot do it in that situation. Am I right? And thanks for referencing me to the book. It is really helpful.

Comment: So, what is a model/structure? I was convinced that it is a triple: $\mathfrak{A} = <A, \Sigma^f_A, \Sigma^r_A$ where $\Sigma^f_A$ contains functional symbols, $\Sigma^r_A$ contains relations and $A$ is just universum for $\mathfrak{A}$. So, if we change one element ( we change a signature of functions) we change the triple.

Comment: Ok, So let $\mathfrak{A} = \langle A,R_1,\ldots, R_n, F_1,\ldots , F_m, \{ c_i \mid i ∈ I \} \rangle$. Now, I add the constant $a_c$. $a_c$ is a constant function- just name for $a$. So: $\mathfrak{A}_c = \langle A,R_1,\ldots, R_n, F_1,\ldots , F_m, a_c \{ c_i \mid i ∈ I \} \rangle $
Therefore, the structure $\mathfrak{A} \neq \mathfrak{A}_c$

Comment: ok, Does it depend on definition of the structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Mauro is answering a slightly different question than the one you're asking. There *are* examples of structures which "don't have enough terms" (structures and theories which *do* have enough terms are said to have the *witness property* or [*existence property*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_and_existence_properties#Existence_property)). For example, *any* structure in a language which only has relation symbols! There are no terms at all in such a language (besides free variables), but of course we have plenty of true existential sentences - e.g. "$\exists x(x=x)$."

Mauro's point is that any structure $\mathfrak{A}$ has a *canonical* expansion $\mathfrak{A}_{+}$ where we add a new constant symbol for each element of the domain, and this expansion does indeed have the witness property. And it is frequently useful, in trying to understand $\mathfrak{A}$, to study $\mathfrak{A}_+$. However, the two are indeed different structures, and the general answer to you question is: **no**, the witness property does not always hold.

Comment: So, does my answer is correct?

Comment: @logic Yes it is.

Answer (score 0):

We can see :

- Herbert Enderton, [A Mathematical Introduction to Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=dVncCl_EtUkC&pg=PA80) (2nd ed - 2001), page 80 :

> A structure for a first-order language will tell us :
>
> 1. What collection of things the universal quantifier symbol ($∀$) refers to, and
> 2. What the other parameters (the predicate and function symbols) denote.
>
> Formally, a *structure* $\mathfrak A$ for our given first-order language is a function whose domain is the set of parameters [i.e. the symbols of the language] and such that
>
> > 1. $\mathfrak A$ assigns to the quantifier symbol $∀$ a nonempty set $|\mathfrak A|$ called the *universe* (or *domain*) of $\mathfrak A$.
> > 2. $\mathfrak A$ assigns to each $n$-place predicate symbol $P$ an $n$-ary relation $P^{$\mathfrak A} \subseteq |\mathfrak A|^n$; i.e., $P^{$\mathfrak A}$ is a set of $n$-tuples of members of the universe.
> > 3. $\mathfrak A$ assigns to each constant symbol $c$ a member $c^{$\mathfrak A}$ of the universe $|\mathfrak A|$.
> > 4. $|\mathfrak A|$ assigns to each $n$-place function symbol $f$ an $n$-ary operation $f^{$\mathfrak A}$ on $|\mathfrak A|$; i.e., $f^{$\mathfrak A} : |\mathfrak A|^n \to  |\mathfrak A|$.

Thus : YES, if we "enlarge" the language adding more *constant* symbols, we modifiy the *structure* because we have to modify the point 3 above of the mapping.

---

Setting apart the terminology, this is very similar to what happens in Computability & Logic, [page 117](https://books.google.it/books?id=0LpsXQV2kXAC&pg=PA117) :

> Let us say that in the interpretation $\mathcal M$ the individual $m$ satisfies $F(x)$, and write $\mathcal M \vDash F[m]$, to mean "if we considered the extended language $L \cup \{ c \}$ obtained by adding a new constant $c$ in to our given language $L$, and if among all the extensions of our given interpretation $\mathcal M$ to an interpretation of this extended language we
>   considered the one $\mathcal M^c_m$ that assigns to $c$ the denotation $m$, then $F(c)$ would be true":
>
> > $\mathcal M \vDash F[m]$ if and only if $\mathcal M^c_m \vDash F(c)$.
>
> (For definiteness, let us say the constant to be added should be the first constant not in $L$ in our fixed enumeration of the stock of constants.)

Comment: Therefore, my answer is correct in the sense of Enderton's definition, yes?